# Sorting objects into a hash of types

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I would like to loop through an array of objects and sort them into a product types hash.

The outcome I am looking for is something like this.

```
{ "Bike" => [line_item, line_item, line_item], "Car" => [line_item] }
```

So far I have got the following

```
PRODUCT_TYPES = Hash.new []

Input.cart.line_items.each do |item| 
  PRODUCT_TYPES[item.variant.product.product_type] << line_item
end
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Edit:

This is my input:

```
[#<LineItem:0x7f5994288da0 @grams=0, @original_line_price=#<Money:0x7f5994289220>, @discounts=[], 
 @properties_was={}, @line_price=#<Money:0x7f5994289370>, @variant=#<Variant:0x7f59942898b0>, @properties={}, 
 @adjustments=[], @quantity=1, @source_indices={"12593518772283:86c53a47791a6f36173f4ecc3039ec9b"=>1}, 
 @line_price_was=#<Money:0x7f5994289370>>]
```

Comment: What's your input? What's the output / what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: An array of objects like so.. [#<LineItem:0x7f5994288da0 @grams=0, @original_line_price=#<Money:0x7f5994289220>, @discounts=[], @properties_was={}, @line_price=#<Money:0x7f5994289370>, @variant=#<Variant:0x7f59942898b0>, @properties={}, @adjustments=[], @quantity=1, @source_indices={"12593518772283:86c53a47791a6f36173f4ecc3039ec9b"=>1}, @line_price_was=#<Money:0x7f5994289370>>]

Comment: Great, thanks @JoeAinsworth - I've edited your question to include this, hope you don't mind. Keeps it nice and readable. Have also popped an answer in below. Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem, thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach will be to use [`group_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by):

```
Input.cart.line_items.group_by { |item| item.variant.product.product_type }
```

That should return a hash exactly as desired - the output of the evaluated block is returned as a hash key (i.e. `item.variant.product.product_type`), with the items assigned as an array of values to these keys.

One side note - as you're querying through a few of each `line_item`'s associated records, it's worth `including` these to avoid N + 1 issues, e.g.

```
Input.cart.line_items.includes(variant: { product: :product_type }).group_by do |item| 
  item.variant.product.product_type
end
```

---

Here's another simple way to achieve what you're after using [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object):

```
Input.cart.line_items.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |item, hash| 
  hash[item.variant.product.product_type] << item
end
```

Edit: just realised your question is tagged Ruby not Rails, in which case `each_with_object` isn't available, though you can achieve similar using [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
Input.cart.line_items.reduce(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |hash, item| 
  hash.tap { |h| h[item.variant.product.product_type] << item }
end
```

Note the use of `tap`: `reduce` returns whatever the block evaluates to rather than the object and assigns to the first block arg (in this case `hash`). Using `tap` ensures this is always the hash.

---

In terms of what's 'correct', `group_by` is there for this exact purpose - using this will give a readable approach that's been optimised for the task at hand.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on and if you have any questions :)

Comment: Awesome, amazing answer! If I used group_by and assigned it to a variable and I then wanted to count the total of each product type what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome - glad to help. To do that, you could use something like: `grouped.map { |key, values| [key, values.count] }.to_h`. Basically, this maps the data to to an array of arrays containing key and count, then converts these to a hash. Hope that helps too!

Comment: Within each line_item object there is a 'quantity' field and I'd like to get the sum of the quantity of all line items within a category?

Comment: Try this: `grouped.map { |key, values| [key, values.sum(&:quantity)] }.to_h`. You might not need the `&`, I can't remember off hand.